# About elementary Python

Tags: python

(I am trying to learn by reading some tutorials)
please fix the syntax of below code:

---

```
x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number")):
if x < 10:
    print x, "is less than 10"
```

---

Comment: Drop `:` from the first line. Is it working now? You use colon as a start of an indented code block. After `x = ...` it's not necessary, because `if ...` is not such a block.

Comment: @pawelswiecki That doesn't solve the problem. I am running on iPython or on Sageworksheet on CloudSage and it gives the error , "Please enter a new numberError in lines 1-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projects/fbc29863-8d30-402a-92a7-65a285102797/.sagemathcloud/sage_server.py", line 873, in execute
    exec compile(block+'\n', '', 'single') in namespace, locals
  File "", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line"

Comment: I don't think you have Python-specific problem. I think something is wrong with iPython or Sageworksheet. Unfortunately I have no experience with them. Maybe searching for "EOFError: EOF when reading a line" will help you.

Answer (score 2):

you should delete the : in the first line and also you should add `(...)` after print.

Also, assuming you are using python3, change `raw_input` to `input`.

```
x = int(input("Please enter a number"))
if x < 10:
  print(x, "is less than 10: ")
```

Comment: Please do elaborate a little when you answer. Share the code, with the changes you propose. It makes your answer clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The colon indicates a code block, such as a loop or a conditional which there is none to be found in the first line. You should remove it as it is just a simple statement, getting user input.

Comment: Brahmi No. This doesn't solve the problem. I am running the code on SageCloud and that gives this error "Please enter a new numberError in lines 1-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projects/fbc29863-8d30-402a-92a7-65a285102797/.sagemathcloud/sage_server.py", line 873, in execute
    exec compile(block+'\n', '', 'single') in namespace, locals
  File "", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line"

Comment: What's sage cloud? This is what you should do for Python!

Comment: I just signed up and tried it. It works fine in an IPython notebook without the extra colon.

Comment: Take a look at it [here](https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/bdab5bdb-9602-4c98-a7d0-75b6b46befbf/files/2015-03-01-171928.html).

Comment: Did you have to restart kernel or something to get it to work? Does this behave differently on a Sage worksheet?

Comment: What do you mean kernel? I'm not running Linux, I'm using a web service.

Comment: But there is a "kernel" button at the top and I had to restart it to work. And it still worked only on iPy and not on sageworksheet

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem: If you are using Python 3, `print x, "is less than 10"` should be replaced with the new print() method `print(x, "is less than 10)`.

Comment: This is clearly Python 2, as indicated by raw input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code just as a n alterative as well:

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    user_input = sys.argv[1]
    print("You entered:", user_input)
else:
    print("Please provide an input.")


import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("input", help="Enter something")
args = parser.parse_args()
print("You entered:", args.input)
if args < 10:
    print (args, "is less than 10")
```